# how to declare a foreign key in a model in sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have a model called video.js.

```
module.exports= function(sequelize, DataTypes){

return sequelize.define(
    "video",
    {
        id:{
            type:DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull:false,
            autoIncrement:true,
            primaryKey:true,
            field:"id"
        },
        title:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING(20),
            unique:true,
            field:"title"

        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            field: "createdAt"
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            field: "updatedAt"
        }
    },
    {
        tableName:"video"
    }    
);
};
```

I have created a table equivalent of this model in mysql and I have added a foreign key that is being used in another table called user.

This is the model for the user table.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define(
    "user",
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            field: "id"
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: "",
            field: "firstName"
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: "",
            field: "lastName"
        },
},
    {
        tableName: "user"
    }
);
```

};

I have used the id column in the user table as a foreign key in the video table with a one to many relationship where one user has one or many videos. The problem I am facing is i do not know how to define a model with a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE `video` (`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
   FOREIGN KEY (userId_FK) REFERENCES user(id));
```

How do I create an equivalent of this video table as a model in sequelize?

Comment: I don't see a column definition used in a foreign key definition

Answer (score 0):

The associations in sequelize are well explained here : https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

Comment: The thing is both the models are on two different model files. I dont know how to refer to the user model inside the video model file.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your user can have many videos ?

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            field: "id"
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: "",
            field: "firstName"
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: "",
            field: "lastName"
        },

  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Video, {
      foreignKey: 'userId'
    });
 };
  return User;
};
```

And your Video Model will be defined like this :

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Video = sequelize.define('Video', {
    id:{
            type:DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull:false,
            autoIncrement:true,
            primaryKey:true,
            field:"id"
        },
        title:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING(20),
            unique:true,
            field:"title"

        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            field: "createdAt"
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
            field: "updatedAt"
        }
  }, {});
  Video.associate = function(models) {
    Video.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    });
  };
  return Video;
};
```

Hope this helped you.